# Chrome source with (dropped) sidebar api

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to checkout the chromium source revision with dropped
experimental sidebar api.

Can I get the last revision no from somewhere, before the code was
removed?

Thanks.

[UPADATE]
I could trace to this researching through issues and revisions:
http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=56716

Comment: I think it's recommended procedure to actually post an answer to your own question in this scenario. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: I added a comment because at that point, I could only reach to initial commit revision number. Wanted the last and best one before it was torn off. Will post an answer as I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got response on chromium-extension google group.

> The sidebar API was removed in http://crrev.com/116901 - Mike West

Also, the sidebar directory disappears from source after revision 77159.

[thread here](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/ca1482a642a0835f#)

Answer (score 0):

I once emailed the author of the one sidebar example from google that I remember looking at, if anyone could help you it'd be him: alekseysATgoogleDOTcom

Also, I'm curious about the possibility of hacking a more 'real' sidebar that gets added back to the dom when you re-navigate. Thinking it's my time to start a open source sidebar extension example on github...

Comment: Thanks. It was his code that was added to Chrome source base. Also...its not really dom manipulation like firebug does. It was a real sidebar on browser process level, as my first impression goes, without disturbing the current page dom model. Still playing with it.Its true browser process owns it, so there should be a way to make it tab-independent and persistent like sidebars in Firefox. I will try alekseys when I have more insight.